# Cannot Install Team Fortress 2, home folder too small?

Tags: directory, home-directory, steam

I have very little experience with Ubuntu. I'm trying to install Team Fortress 2 but it keeps telling me that I don't have enough space. I have a 500gb HDD, and at least half of it is free. How do I allocate more space to the home folder so I can install TF2?

And like I said, I have very little experience with Ubuntu, I'd appreciate step-by-step instructions.

Screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error?

Comment: ...How do I post pictures on here. =P

Comment: Click on "Edit"  below your question and then [the words "img"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3dYU5.png).   That will guide you through the process.  And if you haven't already, I suggest checking out the [About](http://askubuntu.com/about) page and [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq).

Comment: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-_zM37NP5spQ/USEOfXzlPeI/AAAAAAAAAA8/r73SSeEefk0/s1600/Screenshot+from+2013-02-17+12:03:02.png

Comment: This works too I suppose

Comment: I'm having a similar issue putting SC2 in my home folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259168/not-enough-space-on-hard-drive-for-tf2/259193#259193) yesterday, that I think should also help with your problem. Please let me know if you need more help.

If you have not "mounted" the other part of the HDD (that is you can't access it in Ubuntu) please add that information, so that I can take that into account in answering the question.